# How to set the backgroundImage in javascript，my code dosn't work，Can any body help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The url of the image is a string variable,like this:

```
var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var source = links[0].getAttribute("href");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeHolder");
placeholder.style.background="url(source)"; //likely to go wrong here
```

I'll be really grateful if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 3):

unlike php, javascript doesn't recognize variables inside `""` strings, so you have to do:

```
placeholder.style.background="url("+source+")";
```

This way you have the variable outside the string and then you have the concatenate (+) operator to join them.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was about javascript, but when making a website, using lots of javascript is a no-no. Vandervals is correct about how to set the background image with javascript, but here is an easier way to do it with CSS:

```
html {
    background-image: url("your_image.jpg");
}
```

Regards,
    Thomas

Comment: Adding on to this answer, if you need to change the background image, a better way that would work in a lot of situations is to use JavaScript to change the class, and in the CSS assign a different image to elements of that class.